# QWidget focusOutEvent not received

Tags: events, qt, qwidget

I've created a date input by subclassing a QLineEdit and a QCalendar. The calender is displayed at the bottom of the QLineEdit when a mousePressEvent is received on it. The problem is with hiding that calendar. I've overridden its focusOutEvent as I want it to be closed when the user clicks somewhere else. But this event is not received at all, I confirmed this by putting a breakpoint in it, it never stops there. I've put a call to `close()` in it:

```
class MyCalendarWidget : public QCalendarWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
    {
        close();
    }
};
```

When I close it from my DateLineEdit, it works as expected:

```
void DateLineEdit::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    if (calendar->isVisible())
    {
        calendar->close();
    }
    else
    {
        calendar->move(mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, height())));
        calendar->show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's not sending a focusOutEvent because it never had focus in the first place; certainly not if the user subsequently typed something in the DateLineEdit.  Capture the focusOutEvent from the DateLineEdit object, and close the calendar at that point; though perhaps you would want to test whether the user clicked on the calendar (in which case it would have focus or at least have received a mousePressEvent) and leave it up in that case (but otherwise close it).

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that there is already such thing in Qt? See the [setCalendarPopup()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdatetimeedit.html#calendarPopup-prop) & [setCalendarWidget()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdatetimeedit.html#setCalendarWidget) of the QDateTimeEdit class. The only difference I can thing of now is that to see the calendar the user will have to click on the right side of the widget, instead of the editing line.

Hope this helps